# Strange issue regarding for-comprehension

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, for-comprehension

I'm a newbie to the whole Scala scene but so far have been loving the ride! However, I got stuck with an issue and haven't yet been able to grasp the reason...
I'm currently working with Kafka and was trying to read data from a topic and pass it around to somewhere else.

The problem is: the println in the inner for-comprehension outputs the lines on the bottom, as expected, but all other prinln's outside that inner for are skipped and the function ends up returning nothing at all (can't even issue a getClass in the test case!)... What might be causing it? I really ran out of ideas...

The related code:

```
def tryBatchRead(maxMessages: Int = 100, skipMessageOnError: Boolean = true): List[String] = {
  var numMessages = 0L

  var list = List[String]()

  val iter = if (maxMessages >= 0) stream.slice(0, maxMessages) else stream

  for (messageAndTopic <- iter) {
    for (m <- messageAndTopic) {
      println(m.offset.toString + " --- " + new String(m.message))
      list = list ++ List(new String(m.message))
      println("DEBUG " + list)
      numMessages += 1
    }
    println("test1")
  }

  println("test2")
  println("FINISH" + list)
  connector.shutdown()
  println("test3")
  list
}
```

The output:

```
6 --- {"user":{"id":"4d9e3582-2d35-4600-b070-e4d92e42c534","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}}
DEBUG List({"user":{"id":"4d9e3582-2d35-4600-b070-e4d92e42c534","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}})
7 --- test 2
DEBUG List({"user":{"id":"4d9e3582-2d35-4600-b070-e4d92e42c534","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}}, test 2)
8 --- {"StartSurvey":{"user":{"id":"6a736fdd-79a0-466a-9030-61b5ac3a3a0e","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}}}
DEBUG List({"user":{"id":"4d9e3582-2d35-4600-b070-e4d92e42c534","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}}, test 2, {"StartSurvey":{"user":{"id":"6a736fdd-79a0-466a-9030-61b5ac3a3a0e","age":25,"sex":"M","location":"PT"}}})
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you have in your code is a simple for-loop, for-comprehension is a syntactic sugar around monadic-programming style, i.e `for {...} yield ...` construct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but it's VERY likely that you block after reading last message awaiting next one to come (kafka streams are basically infinite). Configure timeout for kafka consumer, so it will give up if there is no message for some time. There is `consumer.timeout.ms` property for that (set it to `3000` ms for example), which will result in ConsumerTimeoutException once waiting limit is reached.

By the way, I would rewrite your code as:

```
def tryBatchRead(maxMessages: Int = 100): List[String] = {
  // `.take` works fine if collection has less elements than max
  val batchStream = stream.take(maxMessages)  

  // TODO: add try/catch section, according to the above comments
  // in scala we usually write a single joined for, instead of multiple nested ones
  val batch = for {
    messageAndTopic <- batchStream.take(maxMessages)
    msg <- messageAndTopic // are you sure you can iterate message and topic? 0_o
  } yield {
    println(m.offset.toString + " --- " + new String(m.message))
    msg
  }

  println("Number of messages: " + batch.length)

  // shutdown has to be done outside, it's bad idea to implicitly tear down streams in reading function
  batch 
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! I combined your sampled code with @chekkal's suggestion and a couple of corrections but still didn't manage to make it work. =S I was trying to keep it really low level so as to not need to mix Akka features, for example, but can't seem to reach that goal this way. It keeps blocking...

Comment: Also, the code I wrote was heavily inspired by Kafka's own ConsoleConsumer code [link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsoleConsumer.scala) -- including that consumer.shutdown thing...

Comment: @PedroAlmeida you set mentioned parameter to a sensible positive value and it still blocks?

Comment: sort of... With a set parameter, it doesn't output anything and then throws exception. Parameter unset: executes println inside for and blocks indefinitely. In the meantime, I upgraded Kafka to v0.8.1.1 (from v0.8.0) but keeps stalled. =S

Comment: @PedroAlmeida let me guess, you haven't adjusted `auto.offset.reset`? By default consumer will await for a brand new messages, ignoring the ones that already into topic. Set `auto.offset.reset` to `smallest` to start from the very beginning.

Comment: Actually, when I create a Consumer instance, a flag is set to control `auto.offset.reset`. By default, it is set to `smallest`, yes. But changing it doesn't affect the behaviour described.

Comment: @PedroAlmeida can you, please, minimize your code down to reproducible, runnable example and place it somewhere (e.g. github, bitbucket) so I could take a closer look on the issue?

Comment: Hello, @om-nom-nom ! Thank you very much for your kindness! I've posted a snippet [here](http://pastebin.com/0RgQ8JeT). Messages can be sent with Kafka's command line producer, for that matter. No extra setup needed.

Comment: @PedroAlmeida [I mimicked your code](https://bitbucket.org/omnomnom/unblocking-consumer) and it works just fine. Well, there're errors because of improper consuming, but at least consumers do not block. Can you confirm that with that repo your problem is gone (so the problem is likely your local installation?)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a normal behavior since you are doing a for over a stream which can be in theory of infinite size(so it will never end or can hang if it waits for results over an I.O ....).
IMHO I will rather write **for (m <- messageAndTopic.take(maxMessages).toList)** instead of **for (m <- messageAndTopic)**